# ActiveRecord: size vs count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

In Rails, you can find the number of records using both `Model.size` and `Model.count`. If you're dealing with more complex queries is there any advantage to using one method over the other? How are they different?

For instance, I have users with photos. If I want to show a table of users and how many photos they have, will running many instances of `user.photos.size` be faster or slower than `user.photos.count`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 406, accepted):

You should read [that](http://web.archive.org/web/20100210204319/http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2008/2/27/count-length-size), it's still valid.

You'll adapt the function you use depending on your needs.

Basically:

- if you already load all entries, say `User.all`, then you should use `length` to avoid another db query
- if you haven't anything loaded, use `count` to make a count query on your db
- if you don't want to bother with these considerations, use `size` which will adapt

Comment: If `size` adapts to the situation anyway, then what need is there for `length` and `count` at all?

Comment: @sscirus - So that `size` can make a call to them when you make the call to `size` (after it determines which one to call).

Comment: Be careful with just defaulting to size, however. For example if you create a new record without going through the relation, i.e. `Comment.create(post_id: post.id)`, your `post.comments.size` will not be up to date, while `post.comments.count` will. So just be careful.

Comment: Also, if you build several objects through a relation: `company.devices.build(:name => "device1"); company.devices.build(:name => "device2")`, then `company.devices.size` and `.length` will include the number of objects you've built but haven't saved, `.count` will report only the count from the database.

Comment: one thing to mention is that `count` will issue a db query every time. so avoid using it inside loops

Comment: @sscirrus, size is a dangerous command since it's automated, sometimes you do want to query the db again.

Comment: This answer may be missing some important information from the latest Rails documentation (currently Rails 5.2). The [#length](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-length) method will perform a `SELECT * ...` query, where the [#size](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-size) method will perform a `SELECT COUNT(*) ... ` query.

Therefore `#size` is no longer able to be used "when you dont want to bother with these considerations" as it has a different use case than `#length`.

Comment: @Batkins - I know it's a little bit late :) but I have a Q, how `size` detects it needs to call `count`? In other words, is there a case other than `ModelName.all.size`?

Answer (score 103):

As the other answers state:

- `count` will perform an SQL `COUNT` query
- `length` will calculate the length of the resulting array
- `size` will try to pick the most appropriate of the two to avoid excessive queries

But there is one more thing. We noticed a case where `size` acts differently to `count`/`length`altogether, and I thought I'd share it since it is rare enough to be overlooked.

- If you use a `:counter_cache` on a `has_many` association, `size` will use the cached count directly, and not make an extra query at all.

  ```
  class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product, counter_cache: true
  end

  class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :images
  end

  > product = Product.first  # query, load product into memory
  > product.images.size      # no query, reads the :images_count column
  > product.images.count     # query, SQL COUNT
  > product.images.length    # query, loads images into memory
  ```

This behaviour is documented in [the Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache), but I either missed it the first time or forgot about it.

Comment: In fact, prior to rails 5.0.0.beta1, this behavior would be triggered even if there is a `_count` column (without the `counter_cache: true` directive on the association). This has been fixed in https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/e0cb21f5f7

Answer (score 17):

## tl;dr

- If you know you won't be needing the data use `count`.
- If you know you will use or have used the data use `length`.
- If you don't know where it is used or the speed difference is neglectable, use `size`...

### count

Resolves to sending a `Select count(*)...` query to the DB. The way to go if you don't need the data, but just the count.

Example: count of new messages, total elements when only a page is going to be displayed, etc.

### length

Loads the required data, i.e. the query as required, and then just counts it. The way to go if you are using the data.

Example: Summary of a fully loaded table, titles of displayed data, etc.

### size

It checks if the data was loaded (i.e. already in rails) if so, then just count it, otherwise it calls count. (plus the pitfalls, already mentioned in other entries).

```
def size
  loaded? ? @records.length : count(:all)
end
```

What's the problem?

That you might be hitting the DB twice if you don't do it in the right order (e.g. if you render the number of elements in a table on top of the rendered table, there will be effectively 2 calls sent to the DB).

Comment: "If you don't know what you are doing"?

Comment: @SebastianPalma too harsh? ok, rephrase it to be more exact (and polite :)

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes `size` "picks the wrong one" and returns a **hash** (which is what `count` would do)

In that case, use `length` to get an **integer** instead of **hash**.

Comment: I used '.size' on a Collection from a has_many instance and even though there was one record in the collection, size was returning a '0'.  Using .count returned the correct value of '1'.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a flowchart to simplify your decision-making process. Hope it helps.

Source: [Difference Between the Length, Size, and Count Methods in Rails](https://www.akshaykhot.com/rails-length-size-count-difference/)

[image: length, size, and count methods in Rails]

Answer (score 2):

The following strategies all make a call to the database to perform a `COUNT(*)` query.

```
Model.count

Model.all.size

records = Model.all
records.count
```

The following is not as efficient as it will load all records from the database into Ruby, which then counts the size of the collection.

```
records = Model.all
records.size
```

If your models have associations and you want to find the number of belonging objects (e.g. `@customer.orders.size`), you can avoid database queries (disk reads). Use a [counter cache](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter-cache) and Rails will keep the cache value up to date, and return that value in response to the `size` method.

Comment: Both `Model.all.size` and `Model.all.count` generate a `count` query in Rails 4 and above. The real advantage of `size` is that it doesn't generate the count query if the association is already loaded.

In Rails 3 and below, I believe `Model.all` is not a relation, hence all the records are already loaded. 

This answer might be out of date and I suggest deleting it.

Answer (score 2):

I recommended using the size function.

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customer_activities
end

class CustomerActivity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer, counter_cache: true
end
```

Consider these two models. The customer has many customer activities.

If you use a :counter_cache on a has_many association, size will use the cached count directly, and not make an extra query at all.

Consider one example:
in my database, one customer has 20,000 customer activities and I try to count the number of records of customer activities of that customer with each of count, length and size method. here below the benchmark report of all these methods.

```
            user     system      total        real
Count:     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.006105)
Size:      0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.003797)
Length:    0.030000   0.000000   0.030000 (  0.026481)
```

so I found that using :counter_cache Size is the best option to calculate the number of records.