# Should I prepare the 'count' column when I'm showing the number of records each parent has?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have **Parent** model and **Child** model.
Parent has many children.

In index.html.erb, I'm showing the number of records that each parent has.
But I bet it makes laggy when many people are accessing to this page at the same time.

```
<% @parents.each do |parent| %>
 <td><%= parent.child.count %></td>
<% end %>
```

Should I create the column called 'count' in Parent table so that it won't need to calculate everytime it renders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this page, index.html.erb, will be often visited by your user, then I think you should make the 'count' column, maybe paired with counter cache, like this http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column (sorry the video was old but it'll give you the idea).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try to use counter cache.  by the way, what the point of using size instead of count?

Comment: this will help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083219/activerecord-size-vs-count