# How to select data for defined page and total count of records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a table with paginated data and this is the way I select data for each page:

```
@visitors = EventsVisitor
      .select('visitors.*, events_visitors.checked_in, events_visitors.checkin_date, events_visitors.source, events_visitors.id AS ticket_id')
      .joins(:visitor)
      .order(order)
      .where(:event_id => params[:event_id])
      .where(filter_search)
      .where(mode)
      .limit(limit)
      .offset(offset)
```

Also to build table pagination I need to know total count of records. Currently my solution for this is very rough:

```
total = EventsVisitor
      .select('count(*) as count, events_visitors.*')
      .joins(:visitor)
      .order(order)
      .where(:event_id => params[:event_id])
      .where(filter_search)
      .where(mode)
      .first()
      .count
```

So my question is as follows - **What is the optimal ruby way to select limited data for the current page and total count of records?**

I noticed that if I do `@visitors.count` - additional sql query will be generated:

```
SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT 1 AS count_column FROM `events_visitors` INNER JOIN `visitors` ON `visitors`.`id` = `events_visitors`.`visitor_id` WHERE `events_visitors`.`event_id` = 1 LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count
```

First of all, I do not understand what is the reason to send an additional query to get a count of data that we already have, I mean that after we got data from database in `@visitors` we can count it with ruby without need to send additional queries to DB.

Second - I thought that maybe there are some ways to use something like `.total_count` that will generate similar `count(*)` query but without that useless `limit/offset`?

Comment: You don’t have to do another query to get the count of your query. See [`size` vs. `length` vs. `count`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083219/activerecord-size-vs-count).

Comment: visitors.count return count of limited portion of data, i can't use it or size or length to get total count of records

Comment: @Andrew Marshall -  i understand, this is about why 2nd query is sent when calling count()

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you should except limit and offset 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#except .
See how kaminari does it 
https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari/blob/92052eedf047d65df71cc0021a9df9df1e2fc36e/lib/kaminari/models/active_record_relation_methods.rb#L11

So it might be something like

```
total = @visitors.except(:offset, :limit, :order).count
```

Comment: ruby is amazing