# Rails way to COUNT the number of records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, count

I have a model called Partners and a model called Profiles.

A partner has many profiles and a profile has one partner.

I need a way to count in the partners controller to return how many profiles they have.

In the profiles table the column is called : partner_id which is the same as the id column in the partners table.

I have seen the .count() function but cannot work out what I need to return the correct number

Cheers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the best way will be to use `counter_cache` column:

```
class Partner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :profiles, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :partner, :counter_cache => true
end
```

you should add `profiles_count` column to `partners` table. It's not a good way to call `@partner.profiles.count` because it will perform additional query to the database. You should use `@partner.profiles.size` instead. It will get size of collection if it has been already retrieved from the database and perform query in another case.
For more details please visit following links:

- [Count vs size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083219/activerecord-size-vs-count)
- [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column)
- [belongs_to reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to)
- [Optimize rails size query with counter cache](http://web.archive.org/web/20131003134752/http://blog.assimov.net/blog/2011/12/21/optimize-rails-size-query-with-counter-cache)

Answer (score 1):

```
@partner = Partner.find params[:id] 
@partner.profiles.count
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

If you have

```
has_many :profiles
```

on Partner class and @partner instantiated in your controller, then you can do:

```
@partner.profiles.count
```