# Rails .count action with specific :id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, count, ruby-on-rails-4

We have `Questions` and `Answers`, and every Question `has_many :answers` and those answers `belongs_to :questions`.

I want to display the CURRENT count of answers on the CURRENT Question.

i tried in my Answers_Controller :

```
def show
  @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
  @answers_count = @question.answers.count
end
```

and then called on my view `<%= @answers_count %>`.

But i think i'm missing something here, because nothing is Displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that i don't need to call those in my Controller, i can instead just call

```
<%= @question.answers.count %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
@answers_count = Question.answers.count
```

to:

```
@answers_count = @question.answers.count
```

You are finding a particular question in your first line and assigning it to @question, but then are not querying that particular question (using Question instead of @question)

Also, look into the differences between `count` and `size` to make sure you are not querying the DB more than you have to -- this is a good discussion: [ActiveRecord: size vs count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083219/activerecord-size-vs-count)

Comment: Found it, i can call directly @question.answers.count. For some reason in the past this didnt worked and the aproach in my Question worked. Now it works simply like that.