# star rating rails 4 jquery ajax javascript raty

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, raty

I am attempting to follow this tutorial and I am getting stuck: [Adding a 5 star ratings feature to a Rails 4 model](http://paweljaniak.co.za/2013/07/25/5-star-ratings-with-rails/).

Im a begginer with javascript and ajax so I spent a few hours learning how ajax works with javascript. I believe the problem has to do with where the `average_rating` method is (rails problem?).

```
def average_rating
  ratings.sum(:score) / ratings.size
end
```

Currently I have followed the tutorial exactly how it says, while replacing comment with review. In the tutorial it says to define the average_rating in the comment model (mine is in the review model), and I am not sure why I would do that.

Also I have added this (not sure if It belongs in the current controller or if it belongs in rating controller):

```
#this is the controller used for the view which displays the stars
def page
  @rating = Rating.where(review_id: @review.id, user_id: @current_user.id).first
  unless @rating
    @rating = Rating.create(review_id: @review.id, user_id: @current_user.id, score: 0)
  end
end
```

When I try to load the page here is the error I get: `ZeroDivisionError` below it says `divided by 0` and it highlights this line `score: <%= @review.average_rating %>,`

**UPDATE** When I delete this script from the view which has the average_rating, the stars show for my_rating. So something is messing up with the average part:

```
<script> #did not delete this line
  $('#star').raty({
    readOnly: true,
    score: <%= @review.average_rating %>,
    path: '/assets'
  });
```

Deleted part^^^

Comment: `ratings.size` Is probably 0? Maybe use a conditional in `average_rating` that accounts for a lack of ratings?

Comment: could you explain more? im not sure what you mean. I have 2 ratings entered manually from rails console in the rating model and both have different values for score

Comment: You are receiving a `ZeroDivisionError` and it looks like the `ratings.size` is somehow 0, even though you've manually added two ratings. Why don't you try replacing `ratings.size` with `1` and see? Or maybe comment out that line and do `ratings.inspect`?

Comment: If I replace ratings.size with 1 then the page loads with no stars (I have the javascript <script> in my view). If I comment out the line and type ratings.inspect then it loads the page again with no stars in my view

Answer (score 0):

Basically, i would love to get more info, but here are some pointers that might help:

- **make sure the relation is working**: make sure you have `has_many :ratings` for the user/review and 'belongs_to :user/:review' for the ratings. other direction- are you getting the ratings in a controller method? if so, consider changing it to @ratings.
- **use first_or_XXXX** - this is a great rails option to save conditional instantiation. there is [first_or_create](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create) that would do exactly what you did:

`Rating.where(review_id: @review.id, user_id: @current_user.id).first_or_create do |rating|
    rating.score = 0
end`

- finally, **ratings.size, will not update after create**, which might explain the zero devision. read more in [this question's selected answer and comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083219/activerecord-size-vs-count). Therefore, it's recommended to use count (will check on the db, so only saved ratings will be counted) or length (i.e. user/review.ratings.length which will count also built (not saved) objects.

hope that helps.