# Performance gains of collection size: select(1).length vs. count with ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, arrays

**Simplified Question**
Why is `SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE {constraints}` followed by Rails' array.length performing faster than `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table where {constraints}`, and is memory-bloat a concern here?

**Scenario**

Somewhat similar to [ActiveRecord: size vs count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083219/activerecord-size-vs-count), I am working in a Rails app with ActiveRecord models, and have found that calling `ar_query.select(1).length` is typically faster than `ar_query.count`, and in many cases is a multiple 500+% faster. I'm assuming that the former involves more memory in Rails to process the array than count does, as the latter returns a single scalar directly from the database's COUNT (1) function. The timing difference is a bit counter-intuitive unless there is something under the covers.

This code is used in a highly trafficked area, and can get called many times per second, so performance is key, but I don't want to unnecessarily bog down the site with memory inflation if I don't need to.

Comment: This question is more a MySQL one than a rails one, I think you should modify it very well to bring the attention of more MySQL gurus on SO.

Comment: Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2710621/368167).

Comment: Thanks @TamerShlash this is great and has set me in the right direction to consider this from a MySQL perspective; the memory issue with calling .length on an array is fairly trivial, so will focus on my needs with the specific queries I'm using. Thanks again.