# ActiveRecord saves invalid model within transaction and does no rollback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, transactions

I have models

```
class Agency < ActiveRecord::Base
  SPECIALIZATIONS_LIMIT = 5

  has_many :specializations
  has_many :cruise_lines, through: :specializations

  protected 

    def validate_specializations_limit
      errors.add(:base, "Agency specializations max limit is #{SPECIALIZATIONS_LIMIT}. Deselect some before saving.") if specializations.count > SPECIALIZATIONS_LIMIT
    end
end

class CruiseLine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :specializations
  has_many :agencies, through: :specializations
end

class Specialization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :agency, inverse_of: :specializations
  belongs_to :cruise_line, inverse_of: :specializations
end
```

And method updating agency specializations that does no rollback when saving data if agency is invalid (returns `true` even if limit is exceeded). What is wrong with this transaction?

```
module SpecializationService
  def self.update_agency_specializations(agency, params)
    attributes = params.require(:agency).permit( { cruise_line_ids: [] } )

    persisted = true
    begin 
      Agency.transaction do 
        agency.specializations.destroy_all
        attributes[:cruise_line_ids].select{ |x| x.to_i > 0 }.each do |cruise_line_id|
          agency.specializations.build(cruise_line_id: cruise_line_id)
        end
        agency.save!
      end 
    rescue RecordInvalid => e
      persisted = false
    end
    persisted
  end
end
```

When I try to save data like this (returns `false` if limit exceeded) - it shows error flash message, but relations are saved anyways, so that agency is again invalid.

```
module SpecializationService
  def self.update_agency_specializations(agency, params)
    attributes = params.require(:agency).permit( { cruise_line_ids: [] } )

    agency.cruise_line_ids = attributes[:cruise_line_ids].select{ |x| x.to_i > 0 }
    agency.save
    !agency.errors.present?
  end
end
```

After saving specializations over limit - agency model can not be updated on other pages, because it is always invalid.

**Update**

I've checked `agency.specializations.count`:

1) before transaction it is correct, agency is valid (if it is really correct, but form contains too much specializations to save).

**2) after destroying specializations and building new ones their count is `0` (why??), so validation passes**

3) after saving count is exceeded (if I selected too many), agency - invalid.

Comment: `specializations.count` seems to be unreliable if the model is unsaved and associated objects are altered. Try inspecting what value is this during validation: it might actually show something valid, save it and this way make it invalid.

Comment: I've updated comment on `count`. It turned out, after build count is `0` :( maybe, `inverse_of` is incorrect somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use .count, use .length.  count uses a call to the database, while length will check the object in memory.

See this post for more about count/size/length:
[ActiveRecord: size vs count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083219/activerecord-size-vs-count)