# In Ruby are there absolutely no differences between 'size' and 'length'?

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

In the documentation for `size`, we can read [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-size), that 'size() is an alias for length'. For `length` ([doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-length)) "Returns the number of elements in self. May be zero." and that length "Also aliased as: size". The functionality may be very similar, but I wonder if the different implementations contain any other features other than returning the number of elements in an array or collection. The words *length* and *size* seem to imply a difference, especially as size would direct me to think of size of memory in bytes rather than number of elements.

Comment: Can you clarify as to which class you are referring to? e.g. ruby's Array, ActiveRecord's Association or any object?

Comment: @punkle, my interest is in multidimensional arrays of integers where if I index an excessively large number of dimensions I get an error thrown as expected, but with size a fixnum comes back. I had put it as an answer but deleted it gathered a lot of negative feedback

Answer (score 9):

It's exactly the same implementation.

You can see in the [source code of Ruby 2.3.1](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_3_1/array.c#L5840) that is an alias:

```
rb_define_alias(rb_cArray,  "size", "length");
```

Also if you check with [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) and [pry-doc](https://github.com/pry/pry-doc), you can see that it's executing exactly the same code:

```
[1] pry(main)> list = [1,2]
=> [1, 2]
[2] pry(main)> $ list.size

From: array.c (C Method):
Owner: Array
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 6

static VALUE
rb_ary_length(VALUE ary)
{
    long len = RARRAY_LEN(ary);
    return LONG2NUM(len);
}
[3] pry(main)> $ list.length

From: array.c (C Method):
Owner: Array
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 6

static VALUE
rb_ary_length(VALUE ary)
{
    long len = RARRAY_LEN(ary);
    return LONG2NUM(len);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there is a difference, but not in a simple `Array`. If you are using `ActiveRecord`'s `Association`, there is a difference, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6083229/1120015):

> - if you already load all entries, say `User.all`, then you should use `length` to avoid another db query
> - if you haven't anything loaded, use `count` to make a count query on your db
> - if you don't want to bother with these considerations, use `size` which will adapt