# How to hide form when there is one instance of the associated model #rails #beginner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a comment like system where the user can add a 'outcome' to a 'decision'. I like to hide the outcome create form to 'hide' when there is 1 added to the decision.

My best guess to accomplish this, is to count the number of associates instances of outcomes to decisions and create a if statement for hiding the form when there is more than 0 instances of outcome.

I tried different ways of accomplishing this but i can't seem to make the counting or if statement to work. I am new to coding for your reference :-).

Can anyone give me a suggestion on how to tackle this?

My code:
controllers/decisions_controller.rb

```
class DecisionsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_decision, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
# gets all rows from decision table and puts it in @decision variable
    @decisions = Decision.all
  end

  def show
# find only the decision entry that has the id defined in params[:id]
  end
# shows the form for creating a entry
  def new
    @decision = Decision.new
  end
# creates the entry
  def create
    @decision = Decision.new(decision_params)
      if @decision.save
        redirect_to @decision
      else
        render 'new'
      end
  end
# shows the form for editing a entry
  def edit
  end
# updates the entry
  def update
    if @decision.update(decision_params)
      redirect_to @decision
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @decision.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private
  def find_decision
# Loads the right entry.
      @decision = Decision.find(params["id"])
  end

  def decision_params
    params.require(:decision).permit(:title, :forecast, :review_date)
  end

end
```

controllers/outcomes_controller.rb

```
class OutcomesController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @decision = Decision.find(params[:decision_id])
        @outcome = @decision.outcomes.create(params[:outcome].permit(:actual, :strength, :weakness))
          redirect_to decision_path(@decision)
    end
end
```

models/outcome.rb

```
class Outcome < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :decision
end
```

models/decision.rb

```
class Decision < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :outcomes
end
```

decisions/show.html.erb

```
    <h1>Decision showpage</h1>

<h2><%= @decision.title %></h2>
<p><%= @decision.created_at %></p>
<p><%= @decision.forecast %></p>
<p><%= @decision.review_date %></p>

<%= render @decision.outcomes %>


<%= link_to "Delete Decision", decision_path(@decision), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>

<%= render "outcomes/form" %>
<%= render "outcomes/outcome" %>
```

outcomes/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([@decision, @decision.outcomes.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :actual %>:
  <%= f.text_field :actual %> <br/>

  <%= f.label :strength %>:
  <%= f.text_area :strength %> <br/>

  <%= f.label :weakness %>:
  <%= f.text_area :weakness %> <br/>
  <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
```

outcomes/_outcome.html.erb

```
<h2>outcome</h2>
<%= @decision.outcomes.first.actual %> </br>
<h3>What i found i'm good at</h3>
<%= @decision.outcomes.first.strength %> </br>
<h3>What i found i'm weak at</h3>
<%= @decision.outcomes.first.weakness %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<h1>Decision showpage</h1>
<h2><%= @decision.title %></h2>
<p><%= @decision.created_at %></p>
<p><%= @decision.forecast %></p>
<p><%= @decision.review_date %></p>

<%= render @decision.outcomes %>


<%= link_to "Delete Decision", decision_path(@decision), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
<%if @decision.outcomes.length < 1 %>
    <%= render "outcomes/form" %>
<%end%>
<%= render "outcomes/outcome" %>
```

Comment: Thx Pardeep! Your solution made it work and made me -> :-D!
i added 
`<% else %> 
<%= render "outcomes/outcome" %>`  to make sure only one of the two is showing.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like standard conditional logic:

```
#app/views/decisions/show.html.erb
<h1>Decision</h1>

<h2><%= @decision.title %></h2>
<% %w(created_at forecast review_date).each do |option| %>
    <%= content_tag :p, @decision.send(option) %>
<% end %>

<% if @decision.outcomes.any? %>
   <%= render @decision.outcomes %>
   <%= render "outcomes/form" %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to "Delete Decision", decision_path(@decision), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```

---

> My best guess to accomplish this, is to count the number of associates instances of outcomes to decisions and **create an if statement** for hiding the form when there is more than 0 instances of outcome.

Sure - it's called [conditional logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(computer_programming))

In your case, you're looking for several potential methods (to determine the size of the associated data):

- [**length**](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.9/ActiveRecord/Associations/AssociationCollection/length) (`Pardeep`'s answer) -- queries the array's length
- [**size**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/AssociationCollection/size) -- either invokes `count` (SQL query) or `length`
- [**count**](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.9/ActiveRecord/Associations/AssociationCollection/count) -- performs db query (should only be used if no data loaded)
- [**any?**](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.9/ActiveRecord/Associations/AssociationCollection/any%3F) -- very similar to length except returns true/false depending on whether any items exist

Good ref here: [ActiveRecord: size vs count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083219/activerecord-size-vs-count)

> - if you already load all entries, say `User.all`, then you should use
>     `length` to avoid another db query
> - if you haven't anything loaded, use count to make a `count` query on
>     your db
> - if you don't want to bother with these considerations, use `size` which
>     will adapt

I used `.any?` because it's the most succinct in this instance.

Comment: Thx @RickPeck, your explanation is very helpful and useful.