# .count method not working on Heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to show a count of array items in the Index view of my app.

In the controller I have the following code in the controller Update method:

```
def update
params[:course][:member_ids] ||= []
params[:teacher_name]
params[:attendees]


@course=Course.find(params[:id])
@count_attendance=@course.attendees.count


@course.update_attribute(:attendance, @count_attendance)
```

In the view I use the following to display the count of array elements

```
<td><%= course.attendance %></td>
```

The count shows on localhost but when deployed to heroku I get the following error:

> NoMethodError (undefined method `count' for nil:NilClass):

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure that your `course` actually has `attendees` in your Heroku database?

Answer (score 2):

```
undefined method `count' for nil:NilClass
```

This means, you are calling `count` on a `nil` object which means, `@course.attendees` is returning `nil` on your heroku database, so when you call: `@course.attendees.count`, it tries to call: `nil.count` and get the mentioned error.

Make sure, you have the `attendees` data for the `@course` in your heroku database and try again. It should work!

You can see if you have the data in the heroku database by logging into heroku rails console: `heroku run rails console`, and then grab the `course`, something like: `course = Course.find(123)` and then see if you have the `attendees` data for that particular `course`: `course.attendees` in the heroku db.

You can also use [try](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try), that way your app won't crash if it calls `count` on a `nil` object:

```
@course.attendees.try(:count)
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained by `K M Rakibul Islam`, your problem is that you're calling `.count` on an undefined variable (`@course.attendees`).

--

The fix - according to this answer: [ActiveRecord: size vs count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083219/activerecord-size-vs-count) - could be to use `size` instead of `count`:

```
@count_attendance = @course.attendees.size
```

If this still returns the same error, you'll want to use some conditional code to make sure you're only calling methods on `attendees` if any exist:

```
def update
   @course = Course.find params[:id]
   @course.update attendance: @count.attendees.size if @count.attendees.any?
end
```

---

[**counter_cache**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter-cache)

A *much* better solution to this is the [`counter_cache` functionality](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter-cache) of Rails:

```
#app/models/attendee.rb
class Attendee < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :course, counter_cache: :attendance
end

#app/models/course.rb
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :attendees
end
```

From the docs:

> The `:counter_cache` option can be used to make finding the number of belonging objects more efficient...
>
> With these declarations, asking for the value of `@customer.orders.size` requires making a call to the database to perform a `COUNT(*)` query. To avoid this call, you can add a counter cache to the belonging model

--

The reason your functionality works in development, but not production, is that your development `db` will likely have `attendees` populated with the relevant data. Heroku uses a separate database, meaning that you have to accomodate for any `nil` responses.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up adding a conditional to check for nil.  Thanks for the :counter_cache suggesting.  I may refactor with this solution.

Comment: @Stan instead of adding a nil conditional checker, you may also want to take a look at try method (look at my updated answer above).