# Is it ok to call ActiveRecord Methods in the view Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, methods

Using Rails 4

I am wondering (and having a hard time finding an answer) if it is OK to call an ActiveRecord method directly from the view, such as:

```
<%= Article.where(approved: true).count %>
```

or

```
<%= Article.where("short_answer is NOT NULL and short_answer != ''").count %>
```

I realize the normal practice would be to store these in an instance variable inside of the controller, but since I am using a partial, I cannot do that.

Is doing this ok? Can it hurt? Is there a better way to go about this (such as a helper method)? Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is doing this ok? Can it hurt?

It's definitely okay, but the problem is that you'll be calling another db query - which is the most "expensive" part of a Rails app.

`@instance_variables` are set *once*, and can be used throughout the view:

```
#app/views/articles/show.html.erb
#Referencing @article references stored data, not a new DB query
<%= @article.title %>
<%= @article.description %>
<%= @article.created_at %>
```

Because the above all uses the stored `@article` data, the database is only hit *once* (when `@article` is created in the controller).

If you call AR methods in the view, you're basically invoking a new db call every time:

```
#app/views/articles/show.html.erb
#Bad practice
<%= Article.select(:name).find(params[:id]) %>
<%= Article.select(:description).find(params[:id]) %>
<%= Article.select(:created_at).find(params[:id]) %>
```

---

To answer your question directly, you would be okay to call that data IF you were only counting database-specific data.

**IE** if you were trying to count the number of `@articles`, you'd be able to call `@articles.size` ([ActiveRecord: size vs count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083219/activerecord-size-vs-count))

The prudent developer will determine which data they have in their controller, and which they need to pull from the db... doing all their db work in the controller itself:

```
#app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @articles = Article.where(approved: true) #-> could use a scope here if you wanted
   end
end

#app/views/articles/index.html.erb
<%= @articles.size %>
```

`Nithin`'s answer is great but won't get past the consideration that you have to determine whether you need to call the db explicitly, or use already-invoked data.

Finally, in regards to using a partial, if you have to pass that data *every* time, you may wish to use some sort of conditional data to determine whether you need to call the db or not:

```
#app/views/shared/_partial.html.erb
<% approved ||= Article.approved_articles.size %>
<% short    ||= Article.short_answer_presence.size %>
```

This will allow you to set locals IF you want, and also have "defaults" set if they aren't set.

Comment: What if we have a specific "find" in the view, any solution for that?

Answer (score 3):

You should mostly do

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
....

  scope :approved_articles, where(approved: true)
  scope :short_answer_presence, where("short_answer is NOT NULL and short_answer != ''")
end
```

In your controller method

```
@approved_articles_count     = Article.approved_articles.count
@short_answer_presence_count = Article.short_answer_presence.count
```

and use those variables in view.

In case of partials, as said my Raman you can do that.

```
<%= render partial: "form", locals: {approved_articles_count: @approved_articles_count, short_answer_presence_count: @short_answer_presence_count} %>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the detailed answer. I will go this route. Just curious though, can it hurt to call it directly from the view like I was? @Nithin

Comment: It wouldn't be a problem, but it wouldn't be following rails DRY concept. Not a good way for lot of things though.

Answer (score 1):

You can always pass these variables inside a partial using locals:

```
<%= render partial: "form", locals: {zone: @zone} %>
```

Its always a good practice to define the instance variables in controller, it does not hurt but you don't end up doing business logic inside a view.