# Ruby on Rails: Count records returned by find_by* methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, doctrine, rails-activerecord

I read about the difference in usage of `size`, `count` and `length` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083219/activerecord-size-vs-count). It makes sense when I use it like this:

```
@posts = Post.all

puts "length: ", @posts.length 
puts "count: ", @posts.count # Makes a database call to count records
puts "size: ", @posts.size
```

All three returns the correct length. However, if I replace `@posts = Post.all`
with  `@posts = Post.find_by(post_type: 'article')` in the code snippet above, I get `noMethodError` errors for size, count and length for the post object `#<Post:>`

#### My questions:

- Why doesn't these methods work with `find_by` result?
- Is find_by in ActiveRecord not similar to findBy() in Doctrine? If not what is the equivalent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `Post.all` it returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` instance - that behaves very similar to `Array`. So you can do the `Array` operations like `count`, `length` or `size` with it.

But `length` selects all the records, loads into memory and counts as regular `Array`. So using it inefficient and discouraged.

But when you use `find_by` it returns  first record matching the specified conditions. So, `length`, `count` or `size` wont work.
you can read about it [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by).

If you want to fetch all the records that matches your query you better use `where`

```
Post.where(post_type: 'article').count
```

You can learn more about how to use the conditions [here.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions)

Comment: Not exactly `Array`, but `ActiveRecord::Relation` instance - something that behaves very closely to `Array`.

Comment: One more note: I wouldn't advice to call `length` on `ActiveRecord::Relation` instances, because unlike the `count` and `size` instead of performing SQL count and simply returning the result, it selects all the records, loads into memory as Ruby objects and counts as it was a regular `Array`, which is very inefficient.

Comment: Nice explanation. So the findBy() of Doctrine would match by where() in ActiveRecord, right?

Comment: @steady_daddy I don't think many people (including me) here know what `findBy()` in Doctrine is, but after a glimpse into the docs (http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html) it seems so.

Comment: That makes sense. My bad! I should've provided the link to docs.

Comment: MarekLipka thanks for the observation. i added the info.
@steady_daddy, Marek Lipka is right. It looks similar.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 3):

`find_by` method is intended to find only one record. You should use `where` instead:

```
Post.where(post_type: 'article').count
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't these methods work with find_by result?

`find_by` returns only the first matched record and you can't run `.count` on a object `#<Post:>`

You can use `where` for that purpose

```
Post.where(post_type: 'article').count
```