# How do I force Rails to give me the count of the number of children in my model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model, has-many, children

I’m using Rails 4.2.7.  I have this association …

```
class MyObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :my_object_times
```

and

```
class MyObjectTime < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :my_object
```

However I notice when I’m looking at a particular record in Rails, it is always giving me “0” for the size of my count when checking how many child items I have.  For instance, when I execute this

```
puts "result name: #{result.name} id: #{result.id} MyObject times: #{result.my_object_times.size}"
```

I get

```
result name: 53rd Annual Lincoln Classic id: 79eaf6ea-284f-4421-82eb-39c3e9450f8e MyObject times: 0
```

But when I log in to my PostGres 9.5 database and run a query, I see plenty of child records …

```
myproject=> select count(*) FROM my_object_times where my_object_id = '79eaf6ea-284f-4421-82eb-39c3e9450f8e';
 count 
-------
   490
```

How can I force an accurate count when checking how many children I have?

Comment: First, change `belongs_to :MyObject` to `belongs_to :my_object` and check again

Comment: Hi, Gvae this a go but got the same result.

Comment: use `result.my_object_times.count` instead of `result.my_object_times.size`
count issue an SQL count statement while size is an array method that will not issue the SQL query in that case
if you used `result.my_object_times(true).size` it might work since the relation array is evaluated (passing true to relation force it to evaluate)

Comment: check this for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083219/activerecord-size-vs-count

Comment: Using `size` should still query the database unless `result.my_object_times` has already been loaded. We'd have to see what else you're doing with `result` to see if that's the issue. Can you tell (in a Rails console, for example) whether the database is being queried? As @mad_raz said, you can use `count` if you want to force it to run a query no matter what.