# Seed file contradiction in terminal and pry console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pry-rails

I have a small problem. I am making a simple project website which has 4 models (users, articles, discussions, comments).

The following associations have been set up:

Users have many discussions and comments, articles have many discussions (and comments through discussions). Comments belong to discussions and users, and discussions belong to articles.

In my seeds.rb file, I have made entries to be put into these tables, and with the correct associations. After making several entries, I have included a

```
puts "Created #{User.all.length} users..."
```

just so I can see in terminal that everything is functioning correctly.

When using `rails db:seed`, the `puts` message will output the correct number for users and articles, but will say 0 for comments and arguments.

However, I can check in `rails dbconsole` that `SELECT * FROM comments;` will return all the entries from the seed file.

In the pry-rails console, associations also seem to be in place. A command such as `Comment.first.user` will output the expected association as per the seed file.

Why does the line `puts "Created #{Comment.all.length} comments..."`
 output "Created 0 comments..." in terminal, but `Comment.all.length` in the pry console output 8 (the number of comments created in seed file)?

Comment: try to use `count` instead of `length` (you can check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6083229/9541423))

Comment: @sovalina The post you linked was very informative. However, I have tried running `rails db:seed` with `count` and `size`, but am getting the same result (not counted in the terminal, but exists in database).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed by putting the `puts "Created #{User.all.length} users..."` line after associations were made.